# display Qprocess output window inside the QT mainwindow

Tags: qt

how to display Qprocess output window inside the QT mainwindow? I am calling ffplay by Qprocess. the video playing in a detached window? how would i play the video in same application QTwindow

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ffplay but it seems that ffplay is opening the window by itself. One approach is that you could try to get the current image and display that in your mainwindow. Every time a new image is available you have to replace the image in your ui with the new one. Of course you have to keep synchronization in mind, since this application is not single-threaded.

In general your approach looks not right. You shouldn't call a program to do that kind of task. Normally you use a library for that.
You should have a look at this example to get an idea what I'm talking about: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-movie-example.html